How to properly mock the mount point for testing a path splitting function?
I have a Python function split_path_at_mount_point that takes a path as input and returns the longest contained mount point and the remaining tail of the path. The function uses os.path.ismount to check if a given path component is a mount point.
Here's the code:
import os

def split_path_at_mount_point(path):
    """
    Splits a given path into its mount point and the tail.

    :param path: The path to split.
    :return: A tuple containing the mount point and the tail.
    """
    components = path.split(os.sep)
    # Start with the assumption that the mount point is the empty string
    mount_point = ''
    # Iterate over the path components, checking if each one is a mount point
    for i in range(1, len(components)):
        current_path = os.sep.join(components[:i+1])
        if os.path.ismount(current_path):
            mount_point = current_path
            break

    # The tail is the part of the path after the mount point
    tail = os.sep.join(components[i+1:])
    return mount_point, tail

I have written some unit tests for this function using unittest.mock to mock os.path.realpath and open (used by os.path.ismount). However, these tests are failing, and I believe I'm not mocking the mount point correctly.
Here's the test code:
import os
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

# ... (split_path_at_mount_point function) ...

class TestSplitPathAtMountPoint(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('os.path.realpath', return_value='/mnt/hdd0/public')
    @patch('builtins.open', new_callable=mock_open, read_data='rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0\n/dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd0 ext4 rw,relatime 0 0')
    def test_mount_point_exists(self, mock_open, mock_realpath):
        path = "/mnt/hdd0/public"
        mount_point, tail = split_path_at_mount_point(path)
        self.assertEqual(mount_point, '/mnt/hdd0')
        self.assertEqual(tail, '/public')

    @patch('os.path.realpath', return_value='/media/documents/report.txt')
    @patch('builtins.open', new_callable=mock_open, read_data='rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0\n/dev/sdb1 /mnt/hdd1 ext4 rw,relatime 0 0')
    def test_mount_point_does_not_exist(self, mock_open, mock_realpath):
        path = "/media/documents/report.txt"
        mount_point, tail = split_path_at_mount_point(path)
        self.assertEqual(mount_point, '')
        self.assertEqual(tail, '/media/documents/report.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

The tests are failing with AssertionErrors for the mount_point and tail values.
Can someone please explain the proper way to mock the mount point for testing this function?
